# Odata: Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata, etl

## Problem

Get the error (see below) when executing an SSIS Odata connection to the [Medicare Data site](https://data.medicare.gov/Nursing-Home-Compare/Provider-Info/4pq5-n9py) despite successfully previewing data.

### Tried

- Running as 32-bit

[image]

- Reinstalling the [driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42280)

> ### SSIS Error in Debug
>
> Error: 0xC020801F at data convert, OData Source [21]: Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager.
> Error: 0xC0047017 at data convert, SSIS.Pipeline: OData Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801F.
> Error: 0xC004700C at data convert, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
> Error: 0xC0024107 at data convert: There were errors during task validation.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the Timeout value from the ODATA connection manager?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83e51f3e-f64b-48d1-b1ed-8d41dd498d47/ssis-odata-connection-issues-sharepoint-project-online-worked-then-stopped-working?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: @Hadi Just did and unfortunately, still get the same issue. I even tried increasing the max connections to 60. I noticed it fails right away like it didn't even try if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its a really dumb thing: use http instead of https despite the Medicare site reference to https

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/72a5752a-22e5-4542-97c3-7a4044e0fea5/ssis-odata-source-works-in-development-but-fails-when-run-0xc020801f

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the SSIS package from within Visual Studio shell, and then look at the oData connection and test it?  I'm having a similar problem, and when I test my connection, I'm getting an Internal Server Error (500) returned from the SharePoint server where I'm trying to connect.